# Uploading multiple files at once - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm following the way shown below, and everything seems okay. But the problem is, I'm uploading more than photo files (by holding `ctrl`), but only one of them is uploading actually. Here my codes:

`views.py`:

```
def school_document(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateSchoolDocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, use_required_attribute=False)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('school_document')
    else:
        form = CreateSchoolDocumentForm(use_required_attribute=False)
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'school_document.html', context)
```

`forms.py`:

```
...
    class Meta:
        model = SchoolDocument
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'photos': ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        }
```

`school_document.html`:

```
<form class="form-container" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data" style="height: auto;">
...
</form>
```

`models.py`:

```
class SchoolDocument(models.Model):
    apply_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Müraciət tarixi'))
    ...
    photos = models.FileField(upload_to='static/school_documents/', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.apply_date)
```

Comment: Please show your model

Comment: @ha-neul, added.

Answer (score 0):

This is an updated answer. Your `SchoolDocument` has some fields plus `photo`field. When you set your model this way, the photofield will only be able to accept one file.

What you need to do is having a separate `Photo` model and `ForeignKey` to your `SchoolDocument` model.

```
class SchoolDocument(models.Model):
    apply_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Müraciət tarixi'))
    ...
    

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.apply_date)


class Photo(models.Model):
    schooldocument = models.ForeignKey(SchoolDocument, ........)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='static/school_documents/', blank=True, null=True)
```

In your forms.py, you will add another field (filefield) to your SchoolDocument Form with the "multiple file" widget setting.

and in views.py, you will save invidvidual file to your `Photo` model

```
files = request.FILES.getlist('image')

for f in files:
    photo = Photo(schooldocument=schooldocument, image=f)
    photo.save()
    
    # Do something about each f
```

Comment: I found answer similar to yours in Django documentation, but don't know what does ```# Do something about each f ``` mean. Just for saving them in database, what should I do there ?

Comment: Write each individual file to the database.

Comment: @MikeStoddart, can you explain it with code example ? I really don't know what to do.

Comment: I haven't worked with file uploads since Django 1.x, so my memory is hazy. But a very quick glance at the Django's file upload documentation, shows:             `instance = ModelWithFileField(file_field=f)
            instance.save()`

Comment: @ha-neul thank you for your quick and detailed response sir, but still I don't know what to do with "each f " ?

Comment: Updated again with what to do with files